# Are native C++ methods counted in dex file method count?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I was wondering if the methods written in the native C++ are counted in the Dex file method count for sake of Dex method count limit.

If yes, how many methods is added to the Dex count if 1 native method is added?

And how many methods does a Java method add to the dex count because I don't seem to have a solid number in every build I make...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get answers we should walk through [.Dex Format](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html). In our case the most interesting part is a `method_ids` array:

> method identifiers list. These are identifiers for all methods
>   referred to by this file, whether defined in the file or not. This
>   list must be sorted, where the defining type (by `type_id` index) is the
>   major order, method name (by `string_id` index) is the intermediate
>   order, and method prototype (by `proto_id` index) is the minor order.
>   The list must not contain any duplicate entries.

Regardless to the fact that number of array records is stored as 32-bit unsigned integer (see `method_ids_size` field) in practice this array can not contain more than `65536` entries. This is because `method_id` operand of `invoke-xxxx` dex instructions is a 16-bit entity and must be a valid index into the `method_ids`. As result records with indices greater that `65535` would be inaccessible by bytecode. All that results in well-known "64K Methods" problem.

So, as docs say - `method_ids` has one record per each method defined by that `dex` as well as for external ones, that are referred by code of defined methods.

Consequently, each time you add code like:

```
public native void foo();
```

to one of your classes - you get one extra record in `method_ids`. This is also true for declarations of an `abstract` methods. Then, each time you add implementation of some regular method like:

```
public void baz() {
    /* ... */
}
```

you get one new record for `baz()` itself and records for all methods that are referenced by `baz()` and are not added to `method_ids` yet.

Native code has no impact to `dex` content at all, since all C/C++ sources are compiled into machine code, that is distributed via `.so` files. These ones use ELF format, that has its own limitations, and is absolutely independent from DEX.